# maplotlib.widgets with FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, widget

I am trying to plot serial data real time using animation.FuncAnimation, and I want to be able to set a target value for the controller. So I want to have a editable textbox on the figure, which is reflected real time by the line labeled `target`, but I can't figure out how to incorporate the Textbox with FuncAnimation. When I put the textbox code outside of the loop function it doesn't do anything (but the plotting works) but when it's inside the loop, the textbox appears in the middle of the figure and plotting no longer works. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
import random


target = float(0.0)
def changeTarget(text):
    try:
        target = float(text)
    except ValueError:
        print(text + " is not a number")

def loop(i):
    t.append(time.time() - tic)
    data.append(random.random())
    target_data.append(target)

    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(t, data, label='data')
    ax.plot(t, target_data, label='target')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Data')
    ax.set_xlim([t[-1]-15, t[-1]+5])    
    ax.set_ylim([min(min(data), min(target_data))-5, max(max(data), max(target_data))+5])
    ax.legend()

    # This part causes problems
    text_box = TextBox(ax, 'Target:', initial="0")
    text_box.on_submit(changeTarget)
    plt.draw()

t = []
data = []
target_data = []

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# text_box = TextBox(ax, 'Target:', initial="0")
# text_box.on_submit(changeTarget)
# plt.draw()

tic = time.time()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, loop, interval = 100)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: Removing the 10x multiplier on the random data shows that plotting does work, but it looks like the window is not updating as it should, and the widget is still right on top of the axes and is not editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this using tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
import random

window = tk.Tk()

# Target entry box
frm_target = tk.Frame(master=window)
ent_humidity = tk.Entry(master=frm_target, width=3)
lbl_hum = tk.Label(master=frm_target, text="Target: ")
lbl_hum.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
ent_humidity.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
frm_target.pack()

# Set Target when user hits Enter
target = float(0.0)
def onEnterPressed(event):
    global target
    text = ent_humidity.get()
    try:
        target = float(text)
    except ValueError:
        print(text + " is not a number")    
window.bind('<Return>', onEnterPressed)

# Figure for plotting
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# "Data" collection logic
t = []
data = []
target_data = []
def loop(i):
    t.append(time.time() - tic)
    data.append(random.random() * 10)
    target_data.append(target)

    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(t, data, label='data')
    ax.plot(t, target_data, label='target')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Data')    
    ax.set_xlim([t[-1]-15, t[-1]+5])
    ax.set_ylim([min(min(data), min(target_data))-5, max(max(data), max(target_data))+5])
    ax.legend()


# GUI stuff for figure & toolbar
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, window)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# Quit button
def _quit():
    window.quit()
    window.destroy()
button = tk.Button(master=window, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

# Run app
tic = time.time()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, loop, interval=100) # interval in ms
tk.mainloop()
```